# How does `body.className div.className` take precedence over `div.className.className2`?

Tags: css, css-specificity

Here is what I mean:

```css
body.class1 div.class1 {
  color: blue;
}
div.class1.class2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body class="class1">
  <div class="class1 class2">
    Hello
  </div>
</body>
```

`div.className.className2` has the most specific element, so I would have thought this would take precedence. But it turns out adding a parent selector takes precedence over an additional classname.

Can someone point me to the rule that explains this scenario? I can't seem to find it easily online.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that only components on the deepest element in the rule are counted towards specificity. That's not correct, every element/modifier in the selector is counted.

- The most specific rule is `body.class1 div.class1`, it has two tag names and two class names.
- `div.class1.class2` also has two class names (a tie), but only one tag name
- `div.class1.class2.class3` would win because it has three class names and class names are always worth more than an infinite number of tag names.

Try it out at https://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: Oh I see now. I thought there would be some precedence given to the deepest child in the selector, but I guess not. Thanks for that useful link!

Comment: I figured that's where you went wrong. Your assessment is correct, it's all the elements of the whole selector, not just the deepest element.